# Monitor wifi connection over time

Tags: laptop, internet, internet-connection, iphone, isp

I have very poor WIFI. My speeds range from about 1.9 to 3 Mbps download speed on a good day. Not only that, but my internet cuts out constantly.

My wired Internet has speeds I can't complain about. Averaging 66 Mbps download, and 4 Mbps upload. Which is great, but I can just use wifi for pretty much all of my devices, so that doesn't really do me any good. I haven't been on wired enough to know if it cuts out.

Every time I complain to my ISP, they insist it must be me because I have good wired connection speeds. I'm positive that I am having wifi issues because of their bad service, but is there a way that I can prove this to them? Like a way that I can monitor the connection to them over a prolonged period of time so I can have evidence that the service truly is periodically cutting out and that I have very low internet speeds.

I've ran Internet speed tests at different times every other day for a couple weeks now, documenting the speeds, but of course they find them inaccurate and won't take them into consideration because they're over wifi. (Which is what matters to me)

All day today, starting early this morning (now past 7pm) my wifi has not worked, but yet wired Internet has. I'm too frustrated to call the ISP because I know they'll insist on it being me again. I've tried on multiple devices, a laptop with Windows 10, and 3 different iPhones, and same result on all of them. I'm exhausted of having to constantly reset my modem and router everyday to see if it helps.

I have Charter Internet, and a decently new Netgear R6100 AC1200 Dual Band Router (they wouldn't stop insisting it was my router's fault, so I gave up and bought a new one). I also have a Netgear Universal Wifi Range Extender, 4-port wifi Adapter. This is the exact same router they'll sell you for extra money every month, so I know it really shouldn't be a problem with my router... hopefully.

I do have a large family, so a lot of devices get connected. There's nothing I can really do to change that, however, I don't think I'm still exceeding the amount of devices allowed to my router (it's one that is for many devices).

It's miserable dealing with this. Anything I can do?

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Comment: Your ISP is right. it's you. try swapping out the router or buying a standalone AP

Comment: Why ask a question with a title like that, your title should match the description.

Comment: I've swapped out my router a total of 3 times so far

Answer (score 1):

If your measured wired connection speeds are fairly close to advertised speeds, it's very likely that the issue is on your side.

- Make sure the router/AP is positioned in an open space.
- Make sure it has a password and that your wireless network is secured with one as well, so that only your family can connect.
- Make sure that no one is constantly downloading large files (e.g. torrents) or constantly streaming video. Otherwise, set up quality of service (QoS) rules to control throughput.
- Connect newer devices to the 5 GHz band if the user is in close range to the AP.
- Ensure that the router/AP can support the number of users that are connecting to it (a common reason for dropped connections is that the number is frequently exceeded).

Comment: 1. Setup daily reboots on your router 2 keep you router in open area instead of a closet